# How to calcualate how many unique set of 6 can i have in a given set.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Hello my question is quite simple i would think but i just cant seem to find an answer. I have a set of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and i would like to calculate how many unique given sets of $6$ can i get from  this set.
In other words for the number $1$
i would end up with 
$[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,3,4,5,6,7]
[1,4,5,6,7,8]
[1,5,6,7,8,9]
[1,6,7,8,9,10]$
I would move down the line with the number $2$ to compare to unique sets of $6$
note:
when moving to two I would no longer do this
$[2,1,3,4,5,6]$ because it repeats my first case above.
its there a formula to figure this sort of thing?
Thanks in advance.

when I work this out on paper i end up with 15 sets 
here is how

```
for 1
     [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    [1,3,4,5,6,7]
    [1,4,5,6,7,8]
    [1,5,6,7,8,9]
    [1,6,7,8,9,10]

  for 2
        [2,3,4,5,6,7]
        [2,4,5,6,7,8]
        [2,5,6,7,8,9]
        [2,6,7,8,9,10]
    for 3
            [3,4,5,6,7,8]
            [3,4,6,7,8,9]
            [3,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for 4 [4,5,6,7,8,9] 
      [4,6,7,8,9,10]
for 5 [5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

after that i cant make any more groups of $6$ thus i end up with $15$ sets.

Comment: I'd be pretty certain there are other questions similar to this on the site that might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is, it is called the binomial, written $\binom{n}{k}$, read $n$ choose $k$. The value is $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$ So, in your case, you have $$\binom{10}{6}=\frac{10!}{6!4!}=210.$$ I hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Forgive my stupidity Clayton I have two problems here. 1 how are we ending up with 210? the "!" operator is what exactly? Also i worked this out on paper and i only end up with 15 sets of 6 so I'm obviously missing something can you help me understand.

Comment: The "!" stands for the factorial, that is, $n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot \cdots\cdot (2)(1)$. So, $$10!=10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1.$$ Dividing by $6!4!$ is what gives you the 210 unique subsets of order 6. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: it makes it more clear  but i just dont see how the resul makes sense. For example i edit my question can you look how i reached 15. Yet this formula is given me 210 im obviously missing something but i dont see what it could be? forgive my ignorance.

Comment: No worries, it is great to ask questions. Now, looking at the subsets you've listed, where would the set $[1,2,3,4,5,7]$ fit into? Also, we can have the sets $[1,2,3,4,5,8]$, $[1,2,3,4,5,9]$, and $[1,2,3,4,5,10]$, for example. Once we've exhausted one "component," which I'm taking to be the last one, change the next index over, so now we count $[1,2,3,4,6,7]$. So on and so forth. Hope it helps!

Comment: THANK YOU! :-D i knew there was something i was missing. Thank you! I truly appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

It exactly the number of ways to choose $6$ elements out of $10$, i,e. [the binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)$$\binom{10}{6}=\frac{10!}{6!4!}$$

Answer (score 0):

[Binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficients) count the number of distinct subsets of $k$ elements from a set containing $n$ elements.  The notation for this is $\binom{n}{k}$ which is equal to $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$